# Compact subsets of $L^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, lp-spaces

The Riesz Frechet Kolmogorov theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of $L^p(\Omega)$ spaces for $1\leq p<\infty$ and equipped with Lebesgue measure to be relatively compact for the Banach space topology.

Is there any similar result known in case of $L^\infty$?
Thanks

Comment: The [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) is such a result; I don't know of any other.

Comment: Thanks. I agree the Arzéla-Ascoli give us a sufficient condition for the case where the open set $\Omega$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R^n}$ since the injection $C(\overline{\Omega}) \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$ is indeed continuous. However, there are (a lot of) non continuous essentially bounded functions so this cannot be a caracterisation (for example any finite set of non-continuous essentially function is compact).

Comment: Actually the theorem you mentioned is the consequence of Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Although the AA theorem is not build for $L^\infty$ but it does give you the result in that space.

Answer (score 7):

For the case of finite measure space see chapter IV section 8 theorem 18 in Linear Operators. General theory. Volume 1 , N.Dunford, J. T. Schwartz

For general case you should recall that $L_\infty$ is a $C(K)$-space for some weird Hausdorff compact space $K$ and apply Arzela-Ascoli theorem.